# Can I try applying multiple linear regression when there is no correlation with independent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, multivariate-regression

Can I still try multiple linear regression when there is no or very small(2 to 10%) correlation (Pearson)  between the Independent variable(continuous) and Dependent variable(continuous). But very small correlation among independent variables(5% to 25%).

1. if regression is not possible, Is there any predictive modeling techniques available to perform analysis on that data
2. Any type of transformation of data would help to perform regression techniques?

Comment: Yes, you can try it. Why would regression not be possible?

Comment: As there is no correlation and linearity,  R square is very low

Comment: As there is no correlation and linear relationship, R square is very low. Would Transforming variable help.

Comment: It seems like one would just accept that there is no relationship between the IV and DV? Or, more carefully-worded, that you have no evidence that there is a relationship between the IV and DV?